# How to install software on a linux server

Tags: linux-server

i have a linux server from bluehost on which i would like to install some linux software. The software i am installing can be run from the command line. (It is [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/)).
How would i go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have (and you certainly do) a SSH access to your BlueHost remote server, you can connect to your server with `ssh` and gain a remote command line access.

Then, you will be able to install Calibre (with `apt-get install calibre` if you're on a debian-based distribution), or with the [classical way](http://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux) but you'll have to deal manually with the dependencies.

After this, you should be able to launch your Calibre server from command line.

Answer (score 1):

How to do this depends on several things:

- the distribution you're using: is it RHEL based (and thus uses yum) or debian based (and thus uses apt as Cedric suggested) or something else?
- What version of the software you need.  Each distribution has it's own policies for packaging and testing software.  RHEL and it's derivates have a long testing cycle and thus the available versions are in some cases not very up to date.  (Though security fixes are backported.)  If you need the latest available version you may need to build from source.